# sending data in JSON

Tags: json

I’m developing a node app with Express. I’m also using MongoDb. There’s a LodgeSchema and it includes geodata like this:

```
geometry: {
     type: {
       type: String,
       enum: ['Point'],
       required: true
       },
     coordinates: {
       type: [Number],
       required: true
        }
```

Now I want to send an array named “lodges” including geodata of all lodge instances to Mapbox API. Here is the code:

```
const lodges = { features: <%= JSON.stringify(lodges) %> }
```

As you might know, the data should comply to the above format in order for it to work. JSON.stringify() is used to convert “lodges” array which is originally in BSON to JSON.
The problem is that JSON.stringify() turns the data to this:

```
const lodges = { features: [{&#34;geometry&#34;:{&#34;type&#34;:&#34;Point&#34;,&#34;coordinates&#34;:[-99.48032409999999,27.5305671]}}.................]}
```

The quotation mark turns to & # 34; and Chrome doesn’t recognize the syntax. What should I do to fix it?

I expected this:

```
const lodges = { features: [{'geometry' : {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-99.48032409999999,27.5305671]}}...]}
```